# Dissociation of ligand

Tags: ions

If a ligand K[Ag(CN)<sub>2</sub>] is dissociated.. Which one is correct dissociation equation?

$$\ce{K[Ag(CN)2] -> K+ + Ag+ + 2CN^-}$$

or

$$\ce{K[Ag(CN)2] -> K+ + [Ag(CN)2]^-}$$

Comment: Dissociation $\ne$ ionisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three different types of dissociation can occur here, the two mentioned by the OP:

$$\ce{K[Ag(CN)2] <=> K+ + Ag+ +2CN-}$$
$$\ce{K[Ag(CN)2] <=> K+ + Ag(CN)2^-}$$

And one where only one cyanide ligand dissociates from the silver:

$$\ce{K[Ag(CN)2] <=> K+ + AgCN + CN-}$$

However, as Klaus points out in his comment dissociation $\ne$ ionization. Ionization is a chemical reaction that generates ions where there were none before. Consider the ionization reaction of ammonia $\ce{NH3}$ in water:

$$\ce{NH3 + H2O <=> NH4+ + OH-}$$

I'm not sure if this type of reaction is possible, although the cyanide anion is the conjugate base of a weak acid $(\ce{HCN}, \ \text{pK}_a =9.21)$. Thus, any liberated cyanide ion could react with water (assuming this is an aqueous solution!), though I would hardly call this an ionization (as there is no net increase in ions).

$$\ce{CN- + H2O <=> HCN + OH-}$$

Comment: Just a note: This [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization) seems to be in contradiction with your ionization reactions. Ionization occurs only when photons are incident or electrons are hit to the atom. Dissociation deals most probably with the splitting of the salts into corresponding ions, particles, or radicals. So, I don't think the last two equations are ionization "reactions" instead they might still represent dissociation. I agree with all the other parts of the answer:)

Comment: The last two equations are acid base reactions, i.e. proton transfers. When dealing with dissociation reactions like the mentioned ones, one must consider water (or another solvent) or pretend it is gas phase. But then these would be ionisations as there are ions produced from neutral molecules.